# Transform non-normal circular data

Tags: regression, linear-model, normality-assumption, circular-statistics

I have a set of time-series data showing event times for two different groups. Let's call them Site 1 and Site 2. My analysis shows one group is circular normal around a 24 hr clock (von Mises distribution); however, the other is not, and instead is circular uniform around a 24 hour clock. I want to continue my analyses by running linear models using continuous, linear, predictor variables and my circular response variables.

My questions are two-fold:

1) Is there a transformation procedure for circular uniform data to meet the assumption group residuals are normally distributed, for linear modeling of my circular data (i.e., event times)?

2) If I include group covariates and/or use AIC to rank models (because AIC does not assume data is normally distributed), is transformation necessary?

Comment: Could you please tell us what these "normality assumptions for linear modeling" might be?

Comment: 1) One obvious transformation is to convert the 24-h data into 12-h data, but the obverse, converting 12-h into 24-h data is not possible. Thus, questions about 24-h data can only be answered with that data. 2) AIC models require modelling residuals as either normal or Student's-t or some other explicit, specified residual pattern solution. 3) BIC is likely better for model selection, and AIC for parameter estimation. 4) Neither AIC nor BIC is a panacea for model selection, e.g., sometimes ANOVA is preferred. 5) Transformation of variables is always a consideration.

Comment: w huber, please see edits to question 1.

Comment: Could you explain what it means for a *circular* response variable--or its residual--to be *normally* distributed?  That doesn't seem mathematically possible.

Comment: a von Mises distribution is the circular equivalent of normally distributed linear data.